# PHP base64_docode saves corrupt image

Tags: php, android, image, base64

I am sending `base64` encoded image to PHP from my android app. Sometime it stores full image (4KB) and sometime (3KB) (Same Image). when I use URL in picasso, image with 4KB size works fine but image with 3KB size does not load it shows decode error.
This is my PHP code (which sometime works)

```
$encodedImage = str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['encodedProfileImage']);
$data = base64_decode($encodedImage);
$file = 'Pics/'. uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
$BASE_URL = 'http://domain.com/TestApp/';
```

I then do SQL operation in PHP to store image path. Is there any chance that next code operation is done on half decoded image(which is corrupt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the part that says `data:image/png;base64`, at the beginning of the image data. The actual base64 data comes after that.

Use below function:-

```
function base64_to_png($base64_string, $output_file) {
    $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb"); 

    $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

    fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1])); 
    fclose($ifp); 

    return $output_file; 
}
```

If you want to use `str_replace` function then may be below way work. I am not sure :)

```
$fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name");
$encodedImage = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "image");
$encodedImage = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $encodedImage);
$encodedImage = str_replace(' ', '+', $encodedImage);
$encodedImage = base64_decode($encodedImage);
file_put_contents($fname, $encodedImage);
print "Image has been saved!";
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: but sometime it stores good image..but sometime currupt. `data:image/png;base64` did this?  can I use this.. `$encodedImage = str_replace('data:image/png;base64','',encodedImage );`

Comment: can i ask one more thing.. after saving at server `$file = 'Pics/'. uniqid() . '.png';
file_put_contents($file, $data);` How can I rename file name from PHP. @ravi-hirani